# On first load, view has empty value but logs value

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have my main view, `ContentView`, using a `LocationManager` `@StateObject`.  I have an `onChange` modifier on my main view that waits for a change in the location.  When I initially load the app, I see my log statement in the locationManager showing in console:

`Current country code: US`

But the modal view shows as empty: "Welcome to !"

If I manually change the location in the simulator to somewhere else, like Canada, I will see the log statement `Current country code: CA` and then the modal view will pop up correctly ""Welcome to Canada!"
Why is the first time not showing in my view?

***Countries.json***

```
[
     {
        "display_name": "United States of America",
        "searchable_names": [
            "united states of america",
            "us",
            "usa"
        ],
        "image": "united-states-of-america",
        "id": 204,
        "iso": "US"
    },
    {
        "display_name": "Canada",
        "searchable_names": [
            "Canada",
            "ca"
        ],
        "image": "canada",
        "id": 205,
        "iso": "CA"
    }
]
```

---

***Code***

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false
    @Binding var countries: [Country];
    @State var modalCountry: Country?
    @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //
        }
        .onChange(of: locationManager.countryCode) { country in
            self.isPresented = true                              
         }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            ModalView(countryModal: self.modalCountry)
        }
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {
    @State var countryModal: Country?
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Looks like you're in \(countryModal?.display_name ?? "") !")
                .bold()
            Button("Show Me") {
                
            }
            Button("Dismiss") {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ObservableObject {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var countryCode: Country?
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 500 // Only update when user moves 500 meters
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest // Highest accuracy possible
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // Handle location updates here
        guard let currentLocation = locations.last else { return  }
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(currentLocation) { (placemarks, error) in
            guard let placemark = placemarks?.first, let countryCode = placemark.isoCountryCode else { return }
            print("Current country code: \(countryCode)")
            self.countryCode = countries.first(where: { $0.iso == countryCode }) ?? nil
        }

    }
```

Comment: It looks like the default value of isPresented is false. And only when an onchange event occurrs is it set to true.

Comment: @noobie yea but it still gets triggered the first time around, hence my modal view showing -- except it has no value.  If I throw a print log in the onchange, it gets printed when the app loads and gets the initial location -- the modal view just doesn't seem to be getting that value

Comment: ok, just a last question, can you try a print statement after  the country has been assigned? This is just to confirm the json was loaded and it found the country.

"self.countryCode = countries.first(where: { $0.iso == countryCode }) ?? nil"


print(self.countryCode.iso)

Comment: Works well for me in my tests. How do you get `countries` into your `LocationManager`.
 It seems to me that, `self.countryCode = self.countries.first(where: { $0.iso == countryCode }) ?? nil` will return `nil` if the `US` is not in that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, using `.sheet(item:...)` and updating the `modalCountry` in the `.onChange(...)`, works for me:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var countries: [Country]
    @State var modalCountry: Country?
    @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(locationManager.countryCode?.display_name ?? "no data")
        }
        .onChange(of: locationManager.countryCode) { country in
            modalCountry = country  // <-- here
        }
        .sheet(item: $modalCountry) { country in  // <-- here
            ModalView(countryModal: country)
        }
    }
}
```